# make the entire background except header grey

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image]

how do i make the entire background grey besides the top bar and bottom footer

its laid out like this

```
<html>

<head>
  <body>
<div id="big_wrapper">
      <header id="header">
          <div>
            <img src="content"></img>

                  </div>
    </div>
<form>
<div class="search-box">
    <input class="search-bar" type="search" name="" placeholder="Search...">
    <button class="text-btn" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</div>
</form>
</header>
<div class="meat">
'content'
</div>
<</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post the CSS you are using. In the mean time, do some reading: [w3schools: CSS background-color Property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp), this really is CSS 101.

Comment: You can update your question to let community members to see your CSS code as well to advise better. You can use CSS `background-color` property to add background color.

Answer (score 1):

Try it,

```
body {
  background-color: gray;
}
```